# MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions for audio url from FIREBASE

Tags: firebase, vue.js, audio, web-audio-api

I am trying to use a vue-audio-visual plug-in by https://github.com/staskobzar/vue-audio-visual.git to visualize the audio url from firebase but it ran into the CORS restriction.
The audio visualizer is used in a child component:

```
 <av-bars
      v-if="currentSong"  
      :bar-color="['#f00', '#ff0', '#0f0']"
      canv-fill-color="#000"
      :caps-height="2"
      :src="currentSong.audioUrl">
    </av-bars>
```

and imlpemented in the parent component:

`<Playbar :currentSong="getCurrentSong" :audioPlayer="audioPlayer" />`

this is rather odd because I have a separate function to handle the audio playing and it is working perfectly fine by also fetching audio url from firebase without running into any CORS restriction.
I have tried to modify the storage and firestore rules to hopefully allow CORS but to no avail.

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 8, 22);
       allow get: if true; // I tried this suggestion
    }
  }
}
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to deal with this annoying error.

Comment: Outputting zeroes for non-CORS-allowed sources is by design, there is no workaround. You either need to abandon visualizing thesese sources, or put the CORS headers on them. I suggest reading the lenghty, but thorough explanation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: To be clear, playing non-CORS-allowed resources with the audio or video element works just fine, it's only a problem when trying to access the data in them, which would be done by the analyser node inside the library you mention.